# Setting the cursor in the element's default styles, or in element:hover?

Tags: html, css, user-experience

Is there any practical difference between the following two?

```
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And:

```
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

[The MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) specifically state that:

> The **`cursor`** CSS property specifies which mouse cursor to display when the mouse pointer is over an element.

So, is there any real difference? Should one be preferred over the other, or are they interchangeable?

Comment: there's no difference. But if you don't have any other styles that you want to set on `hover` then you could write the cursor style on the default state. So you don't write a hover state just for the cursor style.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is a difference, the first is defined when CSS is loaded but the second one will be defined **only** on the `:hover`. Visually we may not see a difference, but if you use an image as a cursor you may have a small delay if you define it on hover since you need to wait for image load.

```css
button:hover {
  cursor:url(https://picsum.photos/90/90?image=1069) 5 5, help;
}
```

```html
<button>wait for loading</button>
```

For the second example the image will be loaded before hovering (you can check the network tab of your browser to notice this):

```css
button {
  cursor:url(https://picsum.photos/90/90?image=1062) 5 5, help;
}
```

```html
<button>no need to wait for loading</button>
```

So better use the second one to avoid any delay and have the cursor ready when needed.