# Will CSS load url() if the selector does not apply?

Tags: html, css, image, dom

Will CSS load a url() attribute even if the selector does not apply to any element in the DOM?

```css
.not-box {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded');
}

div.box {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-512/stackoverflow-2752065-2284882.png');
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> dssa</div>
```

So My Question is that Will the url() inside the .not-box selector load the image even if it is not used in the dom.

I am concerned about the loading time utilized in images which are not needed for the page in css.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: not it will not load it. Even if it's a hover state it won't load until you hover it (related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51357420/8620333 )

Comment: Why dont you try it out? Look into the network panel of your browsers dev tools (like chrome). My bet is "no" ;)

Comment: No it's not, to validate if it is loaded or not go to browser inspect elements > network > img. Here you can see the images that the page only loaded.